# How do I get the star behind the gate in The City?

Tags: b3313

Near the start of [The City](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/The_City), there is a star behind a gate down in the water. The B3313 wiki says I can bypass the gate with a vanish cap, but I'm not able to find it. Where can I find the vanish cap to get the star behind the gate?

[image: Star behind a gate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [Blue Switch](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Cap_Switch#Blue_Switch) has been activated, there will be a box with an Invisibility Cap in town.

From the start of the level, go forward across the bridge and keep going until you go up a slope. Make a sharp right and break the black box with a ? mark. Collect the Invisibility Cap, then head back into the water and swim through the gate for the star.